# Pseudo class :before don't working in a specific button

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, css, child-theme

Currently, i'm building an ecommerce and a small button was running with pseudo class `:before` suddenly stopped working.The site run WP with Divi and Woocomerce. I wish the bellow code back to run:

```css
.woocommerce-page ul.products li.product .button.add_to_cart_button:before,
.woocommerce ul.products li.product .add_to_cart_button:before {
    color: inherit;
    Font-family:ETmodules;
    content: "\e015" !important; 
}
```

The only thing i did before the error was add theses CSS rules to improve Website usability:

```css
.et-cart-info{color: #ee4b4b !important; font-weight:bold !important;}

.gfields{font-size:16px; color:#232323; text-transform: uppercase;}

.woocommerce-message[role="alert"]{color: red !important; border-color: red !important;}
```

This small `:before` must work because is a Add to cart icon. I have tested many ways and nothing work. No problems if PHP spippets are necessary.

Link to the page: [Page with the problem](https://meiasfsb.com/explorar/)

I want to back this icon: [Example icon here](https://fsbmeias.com/explorar/)

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, there's a display none on the `:before` of your button. The following should fix this.

```
.woocommerce-page ul.products li.product .button.add_to_cart_button:before,
.woocommerce ul.products li.product .add_to_cart_button:before {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Wow! I have no words to thank. You saved my day. I needed to fix this little bug by tomorrow. :)